# Create Chain of Responsibility with Java 8

Tags: java, design-patterns, java-8

I have a test task. I have to create Chain of Responsibility for searching files in file system. For example one unit must check file for name and other one check file for size range.

If I use java8 Predicate like that:

1) Define factory methods for unit of chain which return predicate.

```
public static Predicate<File> sizeGreaterThan(long size) {
    return file -> file.getTotalSpace() >= size;
}
public static Predicate<File> sizeLessThan(long size) {
    return file -> file.getTotalSpace() <= size;
}
```

2) Combine predicates with 'and'

```
public class Filter<T> {
    private Predicate<T> filter;
    public boolean test(T file) {
        return filter.test(file);
    }
    public void appendFilter(Predicate<T> additionFilter) {
        if (Objects.isNull(filter)) {
            filter = additionFilter;
        } else {
            filter = filter.and(additionFilter);
        }
    }
}
```

3) Start chain.

In this case, can I say that it is a Chain of Responsibility?

Comment: Do you have a code example?

Comment: @SeanVanGorder add it

Comment: “Chain of Responsibility” is a design pattern. You use design patterns to solve tasks, using the design pattern is not the task.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not a Chain of Responsibility. I would even argue that that pattern does not seem to fit the task you've been given.

Wikipedia states:

> [in] chain of responsibility, **exactly one** of the classes in the chain
>   handles the request

That doesn't really make sense given your requirements. It sounds like a job for [the decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), which is quite similar to the chain of responsibility pattern.

A solution using the *decorator* pattern might look like this:

```
interface FileSearch
{
    List<File> search();
}

class AllFiles implements FileSearch
{
    private final Path searchDirectory;

    public AllFiles(Path searchDirectory)
    {
        this.searchDirectory = searchDirectory;
    }

    public List<File> search()
    {
        // return all files in directory
    }
}

class LargerThan implements FileSearch
{
    private final FileSearch delegate;
    private final long size;

    public LargerThan(FileSearch delegate, long size)
    {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.size = size;
    }

    public List<File> search()
    {
        return delegate.search().stream()
            .filter(file -> file.length() > size)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}

class SmallerThan implements FileSearch
{
    //Similar to above, but with 'less than' instead of 'greater than'
}
```

You can then combine these filters in any order you like:

```
List<Files> searchResults = new LargerThan(
    new SmallerThan(
        new AllFiles(Paths.get("/some/dir/")),
        2000L
    ),
    1000L
).search();
```